# Using classes outside of the current directory in PHP

Tags: php, class, directory

I have two folders in my directory:

- Plugins
- Classes

The Plugins folder contains two files: Sample.php and Plugins.php.

Sample.php is just a class with one function that extends the Plugins class. The Plugins class tries to create a new instance of the base class which is located in the Classes folder.

Plugins/Sample.php:

```
class Sample extends Plugins {

    public $eggs;
    public $pounds;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->eggs   = "100";
        $this->pounds = "10";
    }

    public function OnCall() {
        echo "{$this->eggs} eggs cost {$this->pounds} pounds, {$this->name}!";
    }
}
```

Plugins/Plugins.php:

```
class Plugins {

    public $name;

    public function __construct() {
        include '../Classes/Base.php';
        $base = new Base();
        $this->name = $base->name;
    }
}
```

Classes/Base.php:

```
class Base {

    public $name = "Will";

    public function Say() {
        echo $this->name;
    }

}
```

Index.php includes everything in the Plugins folder and is supposed to execute OnCall(). It is giving the following error messages:

> Warning: include(../Classes/Base.php) [function.include]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Plugins/Plugins/Plugins.php on
>   line 6
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '../Classes/Base.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear')
>   in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Plugins/Plugins/Plugins.php
>   on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Base' not found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Plugins/Plugins/Plugins.php on
>   line 7

Index.php (if it helps):

```
foreach(glob('Plugins/*.php') as $file) {
    require_once $file;
    $class = basename($file, '.php');
    if(class_exists($class)) {
        $obj = new $class;
        $obj->OnCall();
    }
}
```

What I need to do is use the Base class in classes outside of the Classes folder. How can I do so?

Comment: Where's the code for your index.php? If that's the script showing an error and loading the classes, we'll need to see it.

Comment: @helion3 Oops. Now added it along with the error messages.

Comment: Try using an absolute path to `Classes/Base.php` instead of a relative path.

Comment: I've fixed the including error, but it still won't display the name variable.

Comment: I fixed it by adding `require_once 'Classes/Base.php';
$GLOBALS['base'] = new Base();` to index.php, and changing `$this->base` to `$GLOBALS['base']` and `$this->name` to `$this->base->name` in Plugins.php. It now outputs `100 eggs cost 10 pounds, the 100 year old!` instead of `100 eggs cost 10 pounds, Will the 100 year old!`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take advantage of `__autoload` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php)

Using this function will allow you to load up your classes easily no matter what directory they're in.

Simple Example:

```
function __autoload($classname) {
  $path = "path/to/Classes/$classname.php";
  if(file_exists($path)) {
    require_once $path;
  }
}
```

This means you would be able to remove your `include` statement from your Plugins class and simply keep the declaration `$base = new Base();` and `__autoload` will be magically called and load up the correct file.

Comment: As of PHP 8 __autoload is depreciated. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the parent's constructor in your `Sample` class.

```
class Sample extends Plugins {

    public $eggs;
    public $pounds;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->eggs   = "100";
        $this->pounds = "10";
    }

    public function OnCall() {
        echo "{$this->eggs} eggs cost {$this->pounds} pounds, {$this->name}!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I seem to be receiving the same errors.